# Javascript : difference two ways declare variable in a function

Tags: javascript

I want to create an object. And, in almost code I have read, they often use this style:

```
function student(_id, _name, _year){
   this.id = _id;
   this.name = _name;
   this.year = _year;
}
```

But, I don't know what the difference with below code :

```
function student (_id, _name, _year){
   var id = _id;
   var name = _name;
   var year = _year;
}
```

I have tested for example, `alert` properties to screen, and see no difference.

Thanks :)

Comment: Are the underscores in the second parameter signatures missing intentionally?

Comment: Well, the second example doesn't work. `_id`, `_name` and `_year` are not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare variables using **var** they are only visible in the scope of your function/constructor. They are private so to say.

Using **this**, in this case, goes hand in hand with a constructor function. When you instantiate a student all the values assigned to this will be publicly accessible.

First I recommend renaming your **student** into **Student** with a capital **S**. This is a convention that indicates it is a constructor and you need to use the **new** keyword.

```
function Student(id, name, year){
   this.id = id;
   this.name = name;
   this.year = year;
}
```

If you now instantiate the Student you can access the values...

```
var student = new Student(1, "Name", 2012);
console.log(student.year); // => 2012
```

When using var you can't...

```
function Student (id, name, year){
   var id = id;
   var name = name;
   var year = year;
}

var student = new Student(1, "Name", 2012);
console.log(student.year); // => undefined
```

Comment: So, why often when they're use `this.property = property`, they also make `getter` although its properties are public, and more over, it's violate OOP Principle. Thanks :)

Comment: @hqt If you want to restrict reading and writing of properties you can also create getters and setters for sure. You can do this with standard functions or in later editions of EcmaScript (JavaScript) there are getters and setter built in to the language.See the following question on getters and setters. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384222/does-javascript-allow-getters-and-setters

Answer (score 2):

the difference is the properties are public in the first while privat in the second.

there is no difference of leading var with or without underscore. the second example missmatching the arguments. `id` vs `_id`.

Comment: I might be misinformed, but is there such a thing in JS? Privat and public variables? Do they not just belong to different scopes?

Comment: @JonasG.Drange: Putting them in a scope that no one else can see makes them private.

Comment: @Jonas there is no definition as such private and public in JavaScript,but we tend to think them in the OOP way. hope make sense.

Comment: Not really to do with scope. The first example creates properties of the function's *this* object, the second makes them properties of the variable/execution object. Also, while public and private members can be emulated in javascript, that isn't a good explanation of what is happening here.

Comment: @RobG, I totally agree with you, but I would say it is a simple and understandable way to explain. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
function student(_id, _name, _year){
   this.id = _id;
   this.name = _name;
   this.year = _year;
}
var s1 = new student(1, 'mike', 20);
console.log(s1.name); // give you mike

function student(_id, _name, _year){
   var id = _id;
   var name = _name;
   var year = _year;
}

var s1 = new student(1, 'mike', 20);
console.log(s1.name); // give you undefined
```

Comment: So, why often when they're use this.property = property, they also make getter although its properties are public, and more over, it's violate OOP Principle. Thanks :)

Comment: @hqt In javascript, every property of an object is public.

Comment: So, why they make getter, just for convenience, right ? And see that violate OOP

Answer (score 2):

Its about the scope of the variables.

In your first example, you are assigning id, name, and year as externally accessible properties for student. For example:

```
student.id, student.name, student.year
```

However, in the second example, those variables only have scope *inside* the student function. You cannot access their values from the outside.